# How to get Firebase generated ID?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to update an item in my application so I need an id that Firebase creates:

https://db.firebaseio.com/userid/books/**-L6_e2KsseGzwM8a0YUv**

The problem is that Firebase returns an object of objects, so I returned `Object.values(data)` and now I don't have that id which I could maybe access if Firebase returns classic array..

Comment: Please post the code you've tried

Comment: I tried with `Object.entries(data)`, but it returns two arrays in array, one with a name of object and one with object like: `[[id][{object}]`...

Answer (score 0):

you will get the key of the object by `object.key`. and for value you can do `object.val()`
For multiple object you can try `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()`
Is this you wanted? I can be more specific if you can post the block of code.

Comment: That's what I want but `Object.keys` returns just the IDs in array (names of the object properties)..How to combine these two in one array like key /value pairs ..I tried with `Object.entries` but it returns two arrays..

Comment: You can use `forEach`. for ex: `data.forEach(function(object) {
                const obj = object.val(); const key = object.key; }` here data is the snapshot containing array of objects, object is key value pair.